Nodal Analysis on Supermesh Questions
I am a fresher in electrical engineering, So I was solving circuit analysis question with a current source between two meshes. I am not proficient yet in selecting which analysis to do in which case. So I tried to do Nodal Analysis to this question first. But I got a different solution to the mesh analysis. I think I miscalculated somewhere.
Please, help me in solving this question with nodal analysis approach.

Image source: Practice Problem 3.6 in Fundamentals of Electric Circuits by Charles K. Alexander & Matthew N. O. Sadiku (2016, McGraw-Hill Education)
Edit 1:
Please disregard the already fetched info for mesh analysis like the mesh's current flow, and supermesh. I want to do the qn by nodal analysis. So some of the labeling (e.g. "Exclude these elements") isn't directly necessary for my problem
My work is:
For Center Node,
Current in =current out
or, 6= i1+i2;
applying ohms law,
or, i1= (v2-20) / 6
or, i2= (v2-0) / 14 [Req= 10+4]
or, 6= (v2-20)/6 + v2/14
*But we see, the 6A current flows from lower(ground) to higher potential, the current is taken negative)
or, -6 = -((v2-20)/6) + v2/14 ( I am confused here, should I take -6 or not),
or, solving we get,
or, v2 = 11.2V
After this I do not know, but I needed to have v2=12V so that center branch(2 ohm register) satisfies. Actually, I believe my main problem is assigning sign to registers and applying ohms law with accurate sign.

Image edited and adapted from: Practice Problem 3.6 in Fundamentals of Electric Circuits by Charles K. Alexander & Matthew N. O. Sadiku (2016, McGraw-Hill Education)

It would be appropriate to clean up your diagram and label the parts and nodes before presenting us with the question. Here's what I may have tried:
\$\quad\quad\quad\quad\$
I gather you are looking for the KCL statement for \$V_b\$. That's easy enough. The sum of those current arrows (out-flowing currents) must be zero. So:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_b-\left(V_a=20\:\text{V}\right)}{R_1}+\frac{V_b-\left(V_g=0\:\text{V}\right)}{R_2+R_3}-I_1&=0\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$
The reason for using \$-I_1\$ rather than \$+I_1\$ is that the direction of my arrow is opposite the direction of the current source's arrow. Also note that \$R_4\$ doesn't factor into consideration. It has no impact on the current in its branch. It only alters \$V_d\$.
Compare the above development process with your own.

I’m sorry for the diagram.I came up with a similar equation of KCL. But I got puzzled by the fact that, since current entering the 6 ohm resistor is moving from lower to higher polarity, while solving I took that current(I1) in my diagram as -(I1).

@Yesk Don't try to decide which is lower and which is higher. The universe itself doesn't care about your perspective. So it doesn't matter. So long as you are consistent in approach and interpretation, the correct results arrive every time.


For Center Node,
Current in =current out
or, 6= i1+i2;

You have already made an error right here.
Based on your second diagram, \$I_1\$ is entering the node when it is positive, but \$I_2\$ is leaving the node when it is positive. Since your 6 A source is entering the node you should have
$$6 + I_1 = I_2$$
Meaning, the sum of currents entering the node is equal to the currents exiting the node.
Depending how you like to formulate your KCL equations, you might choose a variant of the same equation like
$$6 + I_1 - I_2 = 0$$
meaning the sum of all currents entering the node is 0; or,
$$-6 -I_1 + I_2 = 0$$
meaning the sum of all currents exiting the node is 0.
In any case, you should have opposite signs for \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ if they are on the same side of the equation.

I believe my main problem is assigning sign to registers and applying ohms law with accurate sign.

You determine the sign when you assign reference directions for your currents and write the KCL equations. Your 6 A source is pointing in to the node, so you should put +6 on the side of the KCL equation representing currents entering the node, or -6 on the side of the equation representing currents exiting the node. You establish the sign this when you initially write the KCL equation. You should not be flipping signs in the process of solving the equations.

Sir, "Based on your second diagram, I1 is entering the node when it is positive".                     I didn't get by what this means. This is because, I1 is directed to be going away from central node.

@Yesk, I'm looking at the notation in the diagram showing I1 and I2 as clockwise circulating currents. I1 goes in to the center node. I2 goes out from it. You can write your equations as either "the sum of entering currents equals the sum of exiting currents", or "the sum of all entering currents is 0" or "the sum of all exiting currents is 0"---- the difference is just moving terms from one side of the equation to the other.  However you do it, you should not have I1 and I2 on the same side of the equation with the same sign.
